# Sentence simple explanation

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, connotations

> He crosses to pose with wife and daughter.

In my native language, this sentence is translated as, *He turns to impress his wife and daughter.* which seems quite odd. The denotations of the words *cross* and *pose* also rattle a lot to translate the sentence meaningfully. Is there any other simple sentence that can be used in place of it?

Comment: What's the context? Note that although ***to cross*** and ***to turn*** are *sometimes* synonymous, they're not usually. And ***to pose*** and ***to impress*** aren't realy synonymous in *any* context. Is he crossing the street so he can "pose" with his family while someone takes a photograph of them? OR is he showing off his ability to turn (in some way) in order to impress his family? OR something else?

Comment: Is there a context for this sentence? It looks like a stage direction. He probably _walks across the room_ to stand in a group with his wife and daughter., Are they going to have their photograph taken?

Comment: The sequence [***crosses to pose with wife and daughter***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22crosses+to+pose+with+wife+and+daughter%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=APq-WBtQv-iaIVpW7ElA0gEhmyXC-fXQPA%3A1644860167171&ei=B5MKYsmMCo-V8gKEoqSACg&ved=0ahUKEwiJrODP3f_1AhWPilwKHQQRCaAQ4dUDCAo&uact=5&oq=%22crosses+to+pose+with+wife+and+daughter%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQ-gtYuRJghRloAHAAeACAAWaIAaQCkgEDMy4xmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-books) (***not*** preceded by "he") occurs several times in Google Books. It looks like a stage direction (in "normal" English I'd expect a determiner before "wife")....

Comment: ...but I can't make out the rest of the context from any of the Google Books hits, so I think this question is going nowhere.

Comment: Where did you find this sentence?

Comment: Yes, it's a stage direction not preceded by "he". It is, Crosses to pose with wife and daughter, and it becomes very difficult to explain to basic learners who don't follow the contextual sense but stick to denotative meaning. And most of the time by following denotations, it is meaningless and makes no proper sense.

Comment: Among several things in this question that confuse me, I don't understand what you mean by "rattle".

Comment: @KateBunting good catch. That comment looks like an answer.

Comment: Stage directions often omit the subject if they follow a speech: the subject is assumed to be the character who has spoken. **Mr. Brown: Good morning, madam. (Takes off his hat)** If you know it's a stage direction, do you know what the family are 'posing' for?

Comment: Also, you can interpret it as _he crosses the stage_. As for [pose](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pose), it's the third definition (position) and not the fourth (pretend).